# How to use WatchConnectivity to get data from iOS app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm fairly new to Apple Watch apps and maybe I am just approaching it the wrong way, but I am stuck after trying to figure it out for several hours and I need some guidance.

Currently I have an iOS app that gets data from `Firebase` and displays some context. (I also store the context in a UserDefault, not for sharing data reasons, but so the user doesn't have to retrieve data every time)

Now I want to create an watchOS 2 app that does the same thing. I know `Firebase` isn't supported for watchOS 2. I was wondering if it was possible to make the watch fetch the data from the iOS app while the iOS app on the phone is inactive or terminated. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

WatchConnectivity provides a way to send message to the iOS app and accepts a reply in completion "replyHandler".

```
public func sendMessage(message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: (([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)?, errorHandler: ((NSError) -> Void)?)
```

But if the iOS app is not active it will launch the app in background and then fetch data.